# Mylyn in Eclipse closes some, but not all, of the opened tabs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars, mylyn

I have an issue with Mylyn and Eclipse Mars (4.5.2), although I can't reproduce it as it seems to occur almost randomly.

Here's what I did the last time it happened :

1. I have a few files opened in tabs, and I decide to create a task in order to be able to come back to them later on.
2. I create a new task from the "task list" in Eclipse (by pressing `Ins`), I give it a name and save it.
3. I try to continue working, but some tabs suddenly disappear (not all of them)

It could be a bug, or something I'm not "getting" about Mylyn. Is it the normal behavior for new task created after opening some tabs? I thought that the task's "context" would update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the normal behavior to reduce the number of open editors. You can disable it in *Window > Preferences > **Mylyn > Context*** by disabling ***Manage open editors to match task context***.

This behavior overwrites the *Close editors automatically* (*Window > Preferences > General > Editors*) which is disabled by default and more obviously: if the number of open editors exceeds a given number then a non-dirty and unpinned editor will automatically be closed. Mylyn extend this behavior by using the task's context.